# Jetty 8; conguration file - enable REST Web Services

Tags: java, rest, jetty-8

I have a jetty 6 instance with some rest web services.

It's configured to deploy pojo services from specific packages.

```
<Call name="addHandler">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context">
            <Arg type="int">1</Arg>
            <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
            <Call name="addServlet">
                <Arg>
                    <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <Set name="servlet">
                            <New class="com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"/>
                        </Set>
                        <Call name="setInitParameter">
                            <Arg>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</Arg>
                            <Arg>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setInitParameter">
                            <Arg>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</Arg>
                            <Arg>
                                 com.example.package1,
                                 com.example.package2
                            </Arg>
                        </Call>
                        <Call name="setInitParameter">
                            <Arg>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</Arg>
                            <Arg>true</Arg>
                        </Call>
                    </New>
                </Arg>
                <Arg>/*</Arg>
            </Call>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

But now I need to upgrade to Jetty 8, and can't find how to configure this. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks In advance!